# Get column based on line level items using GROUP BY - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

[MYSQL TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoxWW.png)

Context: For the above table, I want to create a view "VIEW_A" with order_no, and Manufacture column on a group level.

```
where Manufacture  = A if line level items have `manf` = A or "".
where Manufacture  = B if line level items have `manf` = B
where Manufacture  = Mixed if line level items have `manf` A and B.

How can I solve the issue?
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could count line items 'A' and line items 'B' and then compare the numbers with the total number of line items per order:

```
SELECT order_no, 
       CASE WHEN sum(CASE WHEN `manf` = 'A' THEN 1 END) = count(*) THEN 'A'
            WHEN sum(CASE WHEN `manf` = 'B' THEN 1 END) = count(*) THEN 'B'
            ELSE 'Mixed' END Manufacture
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY order_no;
```